# Ho do I call a webservice deployed in Azure Machine Learning Service?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying Azure Machine Learning Service for the first time. I worked on examples given by MS. I was able to develop in Python and deploy as web services. But I'm not able to use it outside the notebook or any application. Do I need API of that web service? If yes, where can I find it?

I have not got anything to try on. I googled for different methods, but couldn't find relevant link. So I didn't try much there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed using an Azure Container instance you should be able to invoke your model via `curl` on a command line e.g. (assuming you run inference on text data):

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"data":"A sample sentence to run scoring on"}' http://<service.scoring_uri_ip>/score
```

and you should be able to get `<service.scoring_uri_ip>` by using the output of `print(service.scoring_uri)` (assuming the name of your `WebService` is `service`)

Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-consume-web-service) for more examples, and how to secure a web service of that kind.